# How to merge strings in string array according to same substring at the beginning?

Tags: java

Each string in the string array starts with HTML tag name,followed by `':'` and followed by attribute names separated by `','`.

This is the string array,

```
a:accesskey,href,title

a:href,title

div:class

div:class,id,role

h3:

li:id

ul:
```

And I must print,

```
a:accesskey,href,title

div:class,id,role

h3:

li:id

ul:
```

The strings must be merged according to same tags and the resulting string must start with tag name and then must follow the unique attribute names from grouped strings seperated by comma.

Comment: Please format the code in your question. Now it's completely unclear.

Comment: `a:accesskey,href,title` is this an array or an string item of an array?

Answer (score 1):

Use a `HashMap<String,<Set<String>>>`

Pseudocode:

```
for each tag:
    if not in map:
        add to map -> key, new set
    else:
        add all values to the existing set
```

Comment: I was developing the code, while you wrote the pseudocode. :D

Answer (score 0):

```
 String [] unsortedStrings = {"a:accesskey,href,title", "a:href,title", "div:class", "div:class,id,role", "h3:", "li:id", "ul:"};
        Map<String, Set<String>> map = new HashMap<>();
        Set<String> list = new HashSet<>();
        for(String unsortedString : unsortedStrings) {
            String split[] = unsortedString.split(":");
            String [] values = (split.length == 1)? new String[0]:split[1].split(","); 
            list = map.get(split[0]);
            if(list == null) {
                list = new HashSet<>();
                list.addAll(Arrays.asList(values));
            } else {
                list.addAll(Arrays.asList(values));
            }
            map.put(split[0], list);
        }

        for(Entry<String, Set<String>> entry : map.entrySet()) {
            StringBuffer buffer = new StringBuffer();
            Set <String> values = entry.getValue();
            Iterator<String> it = values.iterator();
            while(it.hasNext()){
                buffer.append(it.next());
                buffer.append(",");
            }
            if(buffer.length() > 0){
                buffer.deleteCharAt(buffer.length() - 1);
            }
            System.out.println(entry.getKey() + ":" + buffer);
        }
```

prints

```
div:role,id,class
a:accesskey,href,title
ul:
h3:
li:id
```

Comment: there is no need to provide the actual code, I think the OP can figure out at least that by himself/herself. Guidelines are good though